# table empty empty row background-color

Tags: html, css

I tried to find a solution to my problem on the Internet and on this forum.

Question: why is the background-color not displayed for an empty row?

```css
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .collapse{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        tr{
            background: orange;
            border: solid;
        }
        tr:before{
            content: "";
            min-height: 2rem;
            display: block;
        }
        td{
            padding: .5rem;
        }
```

```html
<table class="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the browser don't like the "display:block" you added inside the table

Comment: you need to put atleast one <td> in the row. you can use colspan to capture the whole row width. in your case it will be ` <td colspan="4"></td>`

Comment: Hi Temani Afif! And which option will you like xD? It is desirable that it works min-height.

Comment: Hi Vijay Kumawat! Yes it's works fine, and most likely I will do so.

Answer (score 1):

For the code to be HTML valid, you need to have td in a tr, if you intend to not put anything inside you can try something like below

```
<table class="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the second box is filled with content

```css
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .collapse{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        tr{
            background: orange;
            border: solid;
            position: relative;
        }
        tr:before{
            content: "";
            min-height: 2rem;
            display: block;
        }
        td{
            padding: .5rem;
        }
```

```html
<table class="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include `<td>` in all cells, even empty ones

```css
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .collapse{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        tr{
            background: orange;
            border: solid;
        }
        tr:before{
            content: "";
            min-height: 2rem;
            display: block;
        }
        td{
            padding: .5rem;
        }
```

```html
<table class="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```