# background color of an empty HTML table cell

Tags: html, css, background-color

I'm trying to set a background-color for an empty table cell:

```
<hr>
<table style="empty-cells: show">
  <tr>
    <td>[</td>
    <td style="min-width: 2em; background-color: RGB(0, 240, 0)">
    </td>
    <td>]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
```

The middle cell of the table isn't displayed with the specified shade of green though.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69028211/table-empty-empty-row-background-color

Try to search for an existing answer before posting a question next time.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code (at least, Edge/Chrome on WIndows10 are happy - the empty cell is green]. If you really have a problem please make your code into a runnable snippet, and test that it really does show your problem, If it doesn't then you need to dig into your actual code using your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly who/where is setting a different background for that cell. As it stands there is no way we can help you as there is no problem presented.

Comment: I think my problem was with the dark theme.  I used an SVG rectangle for the color swatch instead of an empty HTML box and that worked fine, so my problem is solved.  I did look at half a do0zen of the previous issues that S.O. suggested but none were relevant to my problem, nor was the link that one of the respondfers suggested.  It was helpful to note that my HTML worked for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Trying this in a fresh HTML-Doc shows the green background:

```html
<table style="empty-cells: show">
  <tr>
    <td>[</td>
    <td style="min-width: 2em; background-color: RGB(0, 240, 0)">
    </td>
    <td>]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You probably have some other style defined in your CSS, that overrides it, for example:

```css
td{
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

You can use your browsers Dev-Tools to check that.

Comment: What I sent is the entire html document.  there is no other CSS.

I shoud not that I'm using Chrome on Windows10 and that Windows is set to the the "Dark" theme.

When I click on "run code snippet" for your snippet, that cell matches the document background: black.

In developer tools, I selected the middle `td` element and verified all the style rules in the `Styles`  were as I expected.  Can't show them because SO limits the length of comments.

The `Combined` tab just shows black and while for the colors though.

Is there a way to trace how it's computing those styles?